# jasmine stub to throw an object instead of a string

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm unit testing a component on Angular. Here I'm calling a function from an external service and artificially throwing an error in order to test how the component handles the error.

To do so, I need my error to be something like that 
`{ statusCode: 401, code: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }`

However, the Jasmine throwError method only throws a single string passed as an argument. Is there a workaround or a method I don't know so I can throw an object?

Here is my code so far:

```
fit('should display error message if login failure', () => {
    // should throw ({ statusCode: 401, code: 'LOGIN_FAILED' });
    const spyLogin = spyOn(appUserApi, 'loginUser').and.throwError('test');  
    fillForm('toto@gmail.com', '1234');
    submitForm();
    // expect stuff here
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: use returnValue() instead of throwError() from the stub
Then in the returned value your can throw whatever your want using rxjs throwError()

```
spyOn(appUserApi, 'loginDoctor')
      .and
      .returnValue(
        throwError({ statusCode: 401, code: 'LOGIN_FAILED' })
      );
```

Important note: here, throwError() comes from rxjs, not from jasmine spy!